# img tag not showing image

Tags: html, image, https

I created a text file using notepad with the following content, and save it with a html extension.  Then I open it in browser.  The image doesn't show. When I put the image URL in the browser the image shows up, so I know my link is correct.   What am I missing here?  Thanks in advance for your answer.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Image doesn't show</p>

<img scr="https://www.findtaxpro.com/Content/img/logo.png" style="width:90px; height:90px;"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you've incorrectly typed the `src` attribute.

change this:

```
<img scr="https://www.findtaxpro.com/Content/img/logo.png" style="width:90px; height:90px;"/>
```

to this:

```
<img src="https://www.findtaxpro.com/Content/img/logo.png" style="width:90px; height:90px;"/>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

    <p>See Image below</p>

    <img src="//www.findtaxpro.com/Content/img/logo.png" style="width:90px; height:90px;"/>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks.  It was a tuff call to choose one as correct when both are right answers.  As you called out the "src" spelling, choosing your answer. However, a big thanks to @weijian as well.

Comment: @DanA. sure, I really appreciate that and yes the other answer is also just as correct as mine. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
<img scr="https://www.findtaxpro.com/Content/img/logo.png" style="width:90px; height:90px;"/>
```

corrected spelling

```
<img src="https://www.findtaxpro.com/Content/img/logo.png" style="width:90px; height:90px;"/>
```